# Edit or delete contacts in old version of Gmail

Tags: gmail

I am using the old version of Google Contacts. I want to delete my Gmail contacts. Can anyone explain the steps?

Answer (score 1):

To delete a contact:

1. Open the contact
2. Click the "More" menu
3. Select "Delete contact"

To delete multiple (or all):

1. Click the checkboxes next to the contacts you want to delete

   - If you want to delete all, click the "all" checkbox at the top of the page
2. Click the "More" menu
3. Select "Delete contacts".

Unfortunately, if your contacts don't all fit on one page and you're looking to delete all of them, you'll need to repeat this for all pages. You can control your maximum pages size (up to 250) in `Gear -> Settings -> Maximum page size`.

Answer (score -1):

Goto Mail/Gmail --> Contacts (upper left menu).

There, you have Google Contacts.

Click a contact's name. In the top right corner, click Edit if you want to edit it or the dots (more) and select Delete --> Delete if you want to delete it.

You can also land directly on the contacts page by accessing https://contacts.google.com .

Comment: That's the new (preview) version of contacts.